# Solve the differential equation $y^{\prime}+xy=C$ where $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$y^{\prime}+xy=C$$ where $C \in \mathbb{R}$. I have found the integrating factor but I stuck at $$\int Ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$ Can anyone help me the integration or solve the DE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrating factor is correct.  The resulting integral is not going to be elementary and unless you've seen it before in a previous class, it's quite likely you weren't meant to evaluate it.  So skip that step and finish as usual.

$$e^{\frac{x^2}2}y=C\int e^{\frac{x^2}2}dx$$
$$y=Ce^{-\frac{x^2}2}\int e^{\frac{x^2}2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that when using the integrating factor, you do not integrate it again. When using the integrating factor, you are essentially using the product rule where y is a function of x so you multiply the equation by the exp part

Answer (score 0):

You have $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}y) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\frac{dy}{dx}+xy) = C e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Hence $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}y(x) - y(0) = C \int_0^x e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} dt$, which gives $y(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}y(0)+C\int_0^x e^{\frac{t^2-x^2}{2}} dt$.